# How can I remove space remaining after shifting a div upward using "position:relative"

Tags: html, css

How can I "flush" space left from shifting a div upward using position:relative"?

```
.part3_container {
        position:relative;
        top:-80px;
}
```

EDIT:
`.part3_container` is shifted 80px upward, the original place for `.part3_container` is blank, but the flow of the page starts after that space (the blank space). In other words, `.part3_container` was at `top:0px`, now it's at -80px, but the original place (i.e. at `top=0px`) is still taken/occupied  and the rest of the page starts after that space

Answer (score 0):

You can use a minus margin on the bottom of the `.part3_container`.

I'm not a big fan of minus margins but I think this would work best for your requirements.

```css
/* DEMO STYLES */
div {
  height: 180px;
}

.part1_container {
  background: red;
}
.part2_container {
  background: yellow;
}
.part3_container {
  background: green;
  border: dashed 5px black;
}
.part4_container {
  background: blue;
}
.part5_container {
  background: grey;
}
.part6_container {
  background: orange;
}


/* USABLE STYLES */
.part3_container {
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="part1_container">part1_container</div>
<div class="part2_container">part2_container</div>
<div class="part3_container">part3_container</div>
<div class="part4_container">part4_container</div>
<div class="part5_container">part5_container</div>
<div class="part6_container">part6_container</div>
```